# Wildfly 10 - Old certificate showing on website even though new certificate imported to keystore

Tags: caching, certificate, wildfly

I’m having a problem with our Wildfly 10 web application server. When importing our new certificate into our keystore file using the Java keytool, the keytool shows that the new certificate is in the keystore, but the website that is using the keystore still reflects our previous certificate. I've been struggling with this issue for the last 3 days and the current certificate expires in 4 days time. I’ve been trying endlessly to figure out how it is caching the old certificate. I’ve even created a brand new keystore file with new private key and self signed certificate, which is correctly reflecting in the keystore file, but on the web frontend it is still reflecting the old certificate. I’ve also renamed the keystore file, while not pointing to the new keystore file in the standalone-full.xml config file. This resulted in Wildfly not starting up and complaining about the keystore file that doesnt exist. From this I could gather that Wildfly is definitely looking at the right keystore file, but it’s as if it doesnt look at the certificates inside the file. I’ve cleared out the “tmp” and “data” folders as well, as I’ve read that these folders are used to cache content within Wildfly. This did nothing for the certificate issue however.

Anyone that have any ideas what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Frikkie

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out to be another device on our network that was servicing the old certificate to the client. We have a web application firewall that sits in front of the web server that was causing this issue. Also updating the certificates on this device made the problem go away.

Comment: How did you debug this and eventually find out that the application firewall was misconfigured?